# How to add videos with no media player that auto loop and auto play

Tags: video, html5-video

I'm wondering if anyone can tell me how to get videos onto a site that display like the ones on this website where they auto play and auto loop and there are no controls or media player to be seen.

videos here -->  https://urbanelectric.com/

and they seem responsive too

Comment: What's you effort so far ? Do you have any code ?

Comment: I really don't . The code in the other answer worked really well, though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this but I looked in the source code. Here, try this:

```
 <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload muted="muted"> 
 <source src="-VIDEO SOURCE.MP4-" type="video/mp4"> 
 </video>
```

If you want controls, use the controls="controls" attribute
if you need reference, look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

Comment: I will try that.  Thank you!

Comment: That worked pretty well.  Thank you.  Is there a way for me to set the height and width of the video in the code as well?  thanks again!

Comment: Um maybe try using the `height="#px"` attribute and the `width="#px"` in the video tag.